# Accessing check state of radio inputs inside *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a model like:

```
products = [{
    "id":1 ,
    "variety":[
               "color": "#FFFFFF",
               "sizes":[ 
                    {"name":"L"},
                    {"name":"XL"}
                       ]
               ]} ,
 {"id":2, ... } ,
 {"id":3, ... }
]
```

And I have a view like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of products">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let variety of p.variety">
        <img *ngIf="INPUT-REF.checked" src= "{{p.id}}/{{variety.color}}.jpeg">
    </ng-container>


    <div *ngFor="let variety of p.variety">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let size of variety.sizes">
            <p *ngIf="INPUT-REF.checked">{{size.name}}</p>
         </ng-container>
    </div>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let variety of p.variety">
        <input #INPUT-REF type="radio"[name]="product.id" [id]="variety.color">
        <label [attr.for]="variety.color">
    </ng-container>

<ng-container>
```

Right now `INPUT-REFs` inside `ngIf` statements are not in the correct scope but if I flatten my view structure in a way that `INPUT_REFs` inside `*ngIf` statements can access `#INPUT-REF` correctly, everything works just fine but I will get problem styling my view.

Now my question is, how I can access `INPUT-REF` outside it's scope the way `*ngIf` statements get updated correctly?

Thank You.

Comment: _how I can access INPUT-REF outside it's scope_ - what do you mean by scope?

Comment: <div><div #INPUT-REF>{{INPUT-REF}} <-- accesable</div></div><div>{{INPUT-REF}} <--not accesable</div>

Comment: where do you access them?

Comment: look at *ngIf's

Comment: I don't think you can populate local variables (#INPUT-REF) in *ngFor in this way.

Comment: I read this question 3 times and still can't understand what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I think there's only one #INPUT-REF var for the whole form, not one per radio...